# 'str' object has no attribute 'isocalendar'

Tags: python, pandas, calendar

I have a following problem.
I have a column in my dataset Date:

```
df["Date"].head()
0    2021-05-27
1    2021-05-27
2    2021-05-27
3    2021-05-27
4    2021-05-27
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

I need to compute week of the year. I try this formula: `df["date_week"] = df["Date"].apply(lambda x: x.isocalendar()[1])` but I got this error message: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isocalendar'`. How can I fix it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what error is saying your 'Date' column is currently is object so convert it to datetime:

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Finally:

```
df["date_week"]=df['Date'].dt.isocalendar().week
#you can also use: df['Date'].dt.week but it will give you FutureWarning
```